# Kafka bootstrap broker disconnected after adding SSL (with debezium)

Tags: java, ssl, kubernetes, apache-kafka, openshift

I am running containerized debezium and kafka in openshift. I am using the debezium/kafka, debezium/zookeeper debezium/connect and debezium/postgres containers and inside openshift it works fine.

When being in the terminal of one of the pods i can use the kafka console consumer tools to list the topics and also consume events from kafka. Every time I make a change to the database I can see an event using this as an example:

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic topic --from-beginning --bootstrap-server kafka-deployment.project.svc:9092
```

The problem is when trying to access kafka via the openshift external route that points to the service.
When I try this from my local computer:

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --topic topic --from-beginning --bootstrap-server https://route-url:443
```

Instead of the data in the topic I get these messages:

```
[2020-08-19 13:44:40,196] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-82606-1, groupId=console-consumer-82606] Bootstrap broker route-url:443 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-08-19 13:44:40,425] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-82606-1, groupId=console-consumer-82606] Bootstrap broker route-url:443 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-08-19 13:44:40,724] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-82606-1, groupId=console-consumer-82606] Bootstrap broker route-url:443 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-08-19 13:44:41,067] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-82606-1, groupId=console-consumer-82606] Bootstrap broker route-url:443 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Before I had a http route and I was getting SSL handshake failures so I managed to change it to a https route with a valid certificate but it does not seem to connect through to the service.

Comment: boot strap server generally runs on port 9092 or 9093; is there a valid route available to reach to brokers from outside the cluster.

Comment: The target port of the route is 9092 so the port should be like accessing the port 9092 in the pod.

Comment: Yes.. you should be connecting to kafka broker via 9092.. not via 443

Comment: That's not how routes work. The route URL (which is a https:// something URL) is targeted to the port 9092 in the pod. The default port for https is 443 therefore that's where the port 9092 from the pod is. If I set the bootstrap-server to route port 9092 not only do I get the `broker disconnected` error but also `connection to node -1 could not be established`.

Comment: Hi matt did you solve your problem

Comment: HI matt, Any news?